# scheme, search-last funcion whithout several expressions

Tags: function, search, scheme

I must create a function - (search-last x list), i made this:

```
(define (search-last o lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst))
    (if (eqv? (caar lst) o)
        (cdar lst)
        (if (pair? (cdr lst))
            (loop (cdr lst))
            o))))
```

but for ex.
`(define l '((1 . 2) (2 . 5) (3 . 5) (2 . 1)))`

should be 1 but 
my output is 5 i know where i made mistake but i dont know how can i improve it.
I cant use expression with "!" and vector, for, while, set, sort, reverse, list-ref, list-tail, append, length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tail recursive solution using named `let`

```scm
(define (search-last o lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (match #f))        ; when not found match is #f
    (cond ((null? lst) match)             ; return last match at the end
          ((eqv? (caar lst) o)            ; when found 
           (loop (cdr lst) (cdar lst)))   ; we recurse with new match
          (else (loop (cdr lst) match))))); or we keep the old match
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have created your own `reverse` function and reverse the list in your named let loop. But my understanding is that this is not the point of the exercise.

This will work:

```
(define (search-last o lst)
  (or
   (let loop ((lst lst))
     (cond 
       ((null? lst)         #f)
       ((eqv? (caar lst) o) (or (loop (cdr lst)) (cdar lst)))
       (else                (loop (cdr lst)))))
   o))
```

The trick is that if you find a pair with the required first element, the `or` clause will search the rest of the list. If it returns `#f`, i.e. if there is no other such pair in the remaining list, then the clause will return `(cdar lst)`. Otherwise it will return the result of the recursive `search-last` call. The outer `or` does the same with the final result, i.e. replacing #f with the argument `o`.

Testing:

```
> (search-last 1 '((1 . 2) (2 . 5) (3 . 5) (2 . 1)))
2
> (search-last 2 '((1 . 2) (2 . 5) (3 . 5) (2 . 1)))
1
> (search-last 3 '((1 . 2) (2 . 5) (3 . 5) (2 . 1)))
5
> (search-last 4 '((1 . 2) (2 . 5) (3 . 5) (2 . 1)))
4
```

FWIW, here's a tail-recursive version:

```
(define (search-last o lst)
   (let loop ((lst lst) (res o))
     (cond
       ((null? lst)         res)
       ((eqv? (caar lst) o) (loop (cdr lst) (cdar lst)))
       (else                (loop (cdr lst) res)))))
```

Comment: ok, what if for this:
>(search 2 '((1 . 2)(3 . 4)))
2
//when the caar dont exist a output will be an argument.